# How to change starting page, using Razor Pages in .NET Core 2?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, razor-pages

I wanted to set my starting page to /Members/Index.

When I was using MVC, I configured it as following:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Members}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
```

But now I'm trying new Razor Pages approach, and now Members is folder and Index is Razor Page. 
How to set this page in folder as starting one?

I can add Index page in root directory and make redirect there, but I was looking for something cleaner.

Comment: That is the general idea. Razor pages should not influence your routing. What error/issue are you seeing when you app loads?

Comment: @RossBush I have all pages structured in subfolders and no Index page in root directory. Creating additional Index page in root folder with redirect to my starting page in subfolder would work, but it's unnecessary redirect on client side and additional page that does just that.

Comment: An empty Index.cshtml and a redirect to action in your Members.Index(){} should have the same effect. If set up properly the index page may not be needed.

Comment: Is `Members` the root folder for all of your Pages or just the place you want to go to first?  Are your pages under `/Pages`?

Comment: @RossBush I don't think RedirectToAction can be used to redirect to Razor Page. Unless I misunderstood your suggestion.

Comment: You are correct, you can load another view, however you can load a partial within that context. But I doubt that is your intention. My bad, I was thinking partials here.

Comment: @stephen.vakil Pages is root folder. Members is subfolder and I would like to go there first. I would like to achieve the same result like calling RedirectToPage("/Members/Index") in Index page in root folder.

Answer (score 14):

Add the following to your ConfigurationServices function in Startup.cs

```
 services.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
        {
            options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Members/Index", "");
        });
```

If you have another index page you'll probably need to delete or rename it.

Comment: delete or modify old Index page name required to solve the problem

Answer (score 13):

For testing purposes you can change the start page by going to the Properties window for the web project and select the Debug tab. On the 'Launch browser' line enter the starting path

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I am using this way

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddRazorPagesOptions(options => 
    {
        options.AllowAreas = true;
        options.Conventions.AddAreaPageRoute("Home", "/Index", "");
    });
```

My folder structure is:

```
 - Area
   |_ Home
      |_ Pages
         |_ Index.cshtml
   |_ //other areas
```

Comment: `'RazorPagesOptions' does not contain a definition for 'AllowAreas'` compilation error in `.NET Core 3.1`

Answer (score -1):

Try following code at  `AppStart->RouteConfig.cs` :

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Members", action = "Index"}
        );
```