# Default page in ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I need to change the default start page on my project and it's not working. I'm using

```
services.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
        {
            options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Login/Index", "");
        });
```

But when the project starts, it doesn't go to the `LoginController`.

> Update. When I try to change the default Controller to LoginController, it incorporates into the main template without setting the `Layout` at the razor page.

```
 public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
        services.AddControllersWithViews();


    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");

            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Login}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

[image]

Comment: The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46117717/how-to-change-starting-page-using-razor-pages-in-net-core-2) might help

Comment: It doesn't works!

Comment: It doesn't go to the controller, because the call you are issuing is for Razor pages, not mvc.

Comment: How do I solve this ?

Comment: Is your app MVC or Razor Pages?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to redirect all users to a specific route, that is resolved through a controller, you have to define that route like this:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
   routes.MapRoute("default", "{controller=Login}/{action=Index}/{id?}")
});
```

Please note, that while routing to Razor pages works mostly similar, razor pages do not use controllers and are configured differently.

Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: I'm getting a warning about using EndPoints. I'll post my update.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Endpoints with razor, setting a default page can actually be done in multiple ways, to which I will supply a couple. The code you currently have in Startup.cs should work with the methods listed below.

### 1: Create a ActionResult with the same name as your page

By creating a controller with an ActionResult reflecting the path of your default endpoint, root directory should be now be your default page. (Yes, it's this simple.)

```
public class HomeController : Controller {

    public IActionResult Login() => View();

}
```

### 2: Using the `[Route()]` Attribute

This method is useful if you have multiple ways of visiting a view. I do not suggest using this unless the page breaks the general rules of your routing.
It is also possible to make this a default root page without supplying any defaults in your endpoint routes.

```
// Startup.cs
public class Startup {
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection service) {
        services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(jsonSettings);
        services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson(jsonSettings);
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) {
        app.UseRouting();
        
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });
    }
}

// HomeController.cs
public class HomeController : Controller {

    // Putting any Route attribute will remove the default route of '/Home/Login' unless specified. 
    //[Route("/Home/Login")]
    [Route("/")]
    public IActionResult Login() => View();

}
```

### 3: Pages!

Pages are a newer concept in Razor which focus on classes and attributes in .cshtml files rather than controller/action-based project structures. I won't explain specifics but Microsoft have documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) and a basic tutorial [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/razor-pages-start?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio).